# Is Derivative exists means that it is Fréchet differentiable?

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

In this particular article ''about implicit function theorem'': [http://www.its.caltech.edu/~kcborder/Notes/IFT.pdf](http://www.its.caltech.edu/%7Ekcborder/Notes/IFT.pdf),

I found that the author used the terminology  : Derivative, and I wanted to if it's the same thing as Fréchet-differentiable :
For example in the theorem (4) it says that the derivative $Df$ of $f$ exists at $(\hat{x},\hat{p})$,

Does it mean that : $f$ is Fréchet differentiable at $(\hat{x},\hat{p})$ i.e
$$\lim_{(h,k)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{||f(x,p)-f(\hat{x},\hat{p})-T(x-\hat{x})-S(p-\hat{p})||}{||h,k||}=0$$
where $T$ is a continuous linear transformation, and $S$ is a linear transformation.